# Show a character in all available webfonts

Tags: css, fonts

I try to find a fitting standard webfont for the character `>` which fits to the style I imagine.

Is there a way to see this character in all available webfonts?

I would be happy about a website, where I can enter a sentence and will see that exact sentence in all webfonts

Answer (score 0):

If "all avaliable webfonts" means all fonts you know and have listed, or all from some website with listing API, you can simply load each one with `@font-face`.

If you mean "all user fonts", we must to wait for "Font Enumeration API" https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535764

Comment: There are some fonts that are included in all browser